# Javascript: getting element in dom tree when mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mouseover

When using :

```
document.onmouseover = function(e) {}
```

Is there a property which gives me the element in the dom tree ?

For example, I can set a style to `e.srcElement`
But, how can I later access this element to (for example) reset its style ?
And how can I know at which place in the dom tree it is ?
I want to be able to situate it in the whole page dump.

Many thanks.

To solve the problem about reaccessing the element later, I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
var lastelem;

document.onmouseover = function(e) {

  if (lastelem != null){
    lastelem.style.border = "0px";
  }

  if (e===undefined) e= window.event;
  var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement;
  document.getElementById('display').value = target.tagName;
  target.style.border = "1px";
  lastelem = target;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: It's an ordinary DOM element. You can treat it normally - e.g. saving it for later in a variable that's in an outer scope, or using `parentElement` and the like to locate it in the tree.

Comment: (window.event.srcElement is IE-only. For all other browsers it's event.target.)

Comment: Yes, you're right about srcElement.
However, if I want to set a style to this element or target. But later from another function.

For example, I tried this but it doesn't work...


http://pastebin.com/qrSjsY4C

thanks !

Comment: Please post your code in the original question (and use code formatting).

Comment: To Max Shawabekh : Is there any documentation you know about that gives more information about locating the element in the tree ?
Thanks

Comment: You example errors out on the line `var target=...`, `event` is not defined

Comment: @Marcel - His code is IE-specific. I'm guessing you didn't try it in IE.

Comment: @Jimmy: No, his code is incorrect, not IE-specific: he also tests `if (e===undefined) e= window.event;` (in that case, he doesn't have to use parameter `e` at all) and for `event.target`, which aren't needed in an IE-only situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Which HTML element is the target of the event?](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) (on Quirksmode.org, by Peter-Paul Koch). Also have a look at the [`target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-target) of the Event object in W3C DOM Level 2 Event Model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>target test</title>
    <style>
      *        { border: 1px solid #fff }
      .trigger { background: lightgreen }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="trigger">Trigger testCase().</p>
    <p class="trigger">Trigger testCase().</p>
    <p class="trigger">Trigger testCase().</p>
    <p id="display"></p>
    <script>
var lastelem;

document.onmouseover = function (e) {
        var event = e || window.event;

        if (lastelem) {
                lastelem.style.border = "1px solid #fff";
        }

        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = target.previousSibling.tagName +
            " | " + target.tagName + " | " + (target.nextSibling ? target.nextSibling.tagName : "X");
        target.style.border = "1px solid";
        lastelem = target;
};
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I've already read this. Thanks.
What I need is a documentation with all the properties of parentElement, srcElement/target,...

And also a way to locate the element in the dom tree. Say, if I want to highlight the parentElement in the source from the event I received with the mouseover. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Marcel Korpel : This works very well ! Thanks.
Now, I just need to find a way to show the surrounding tags. 
I think I will try with previoussibling and nextsibling.

Comment: @oimoim: Indeed: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#attribute-previousSibling