# onClick on div element won't pass target id

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue in my React.js app with the target id not being passed if a `onClick` event is attached on a `div` element.

This is how I add the component:

```
<MenuOption title="Users" onOptionClick={this.onOptionClick}/>
```

This is the jsx-part of my `MenuOption` component:

```
<div id={title} className="row menu-option" onClick={onOptionClick}>
   <p>{title}</p>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm simply assigning the prop title as the id and the `onClick` event.

Back in the parent component, implementation of the `onClick` method:

```
  onSidebarOptionClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }
```

This does not seem to work since it always logs undefined.

However, if I add the `id` and the `onClick` event to my `p` element instead...

```
<div className="row menu-option">
   <p id={title} onClick={onOptionClick}>{title}</p>
</div>
```

...it works just as expected, the correct id logs at every click.

**So why is not the id passed if the click event is attached to a div?**

I`m using ES6 and babel.

I should clarify that I'm using "dumb" components, declaring them like this:

```
const MenuOption = ({title, onOptionClick})
```

...which is why don't need to use `{this.props.title}` when using it.

Comment: Sorry, clarified my question, see edit.

Comment: This doesn't look like a reactjs problem. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709994/javascript-getting-element-in-dom-tree-when-mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as your Question missing `constructor` but try one of the following--

Method 1 (JSX):

```
<MenuOption title="Users" onOptionClick={this.onOptionClick.bind(this)}/>
```

Method 2 (es6):

```
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onOptionClick = this.onOptionClick.bind(this);
   }
```

Method 3(es-next):

```
onSidebarOptionClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're passing `onOptionClick` as a prop to `<MenuOption/>`, it should be declared as `this.porops.onOptionClick`.

`<MenuOption/>` should look like this

```
<div id={title} className="row menu-option" onClick={thi.props.onOptionClick}>
   <p>{title}</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!